# Speeding up / Optimising this code in C/Java/anything

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, matrix, optimization

So I have two matrices with total 2N elements. So, each one has length of 1xN. What I want to do is to exchange their elements so that one of the matrices has the smallest elements, while the other matrix has the largest of the elements.

The following code does exactly that. There is one problem, when the matrices are above a certain length it takes for ever to finish.

Is it possible to make that piece of code a bit faster? I really cannot think anything now. `max_index` and `min_index` are also typically naive implemented.

Up to `N`=1million items it's relatively ok, takes about `1.0-1.5` minute, but if i need like `N=`10mill or more it never finishes on my laptop.

```
 while (1) {
        int mini = max_index(other);
        int maxi = min_index(data);
        if (other[mini] > data[maxi]) {
          int temp = other[mini];
          other[mini] = data[maxi];
          data[maxi] = temp;
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
```

Example to clarify:

```
other =

    0.5308    0.5458    0.8090    0.8063    0.8874

data =

    0.2901    0.5497    0.9168    0.0882    0.7856
```

After the operation:

```
other =

    0.5308    0.5458    0.2901    0.5497    0.0882

data =

    0.8090    0.8063    0.9168    0.8874    0.7856
```

Comment: What exactly do youe mean by _so that one of the matrices has the smallest elements, while the other matrix has the largest of the elements_? Would it be an option to join both arrays, sort the resulting array and split it into the first and the second half?

Comment: @Codor I updated my original post

Comment: min_index(data); does this return the index of the smallest value?

Comment: Radix sort is one of the fastest available numeric sorting algorithms for worst case scenarios.  It runs in O(n) time.  Here is an implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965564/radix-sort-java-implementation  You would need to combine the two arrays and split them in the end.

Comment: Is it necessary to preserve the order of the elements in any way? If not, sorting should be an option.

Comment: Is this a bubble sort?  You may want to try other sorting functions, such as `std::sort`.

Comment: as @Codor says do you need to keep the order of the elements?

Comment: Please edit your post to include definitions of `max_index()` and `min_index()`.

Comment: Profile.  What percentage of the time is spent in the calls `max_index()` and `min_index()`?

Comment: For large arrays, you may be experiencing *data cache misses*.  The data can't fit into the processor's data cache, so it has to reload; which takes time.  Also, the processor may be reloading the cache to fit in the second array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just requires the [Quick Select algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), with a small modification because the elements are not in a single contiguous array. Quick Select is O(n) (on average), since it does less work than sorting. You simply find element N, which will be the last element int the first array.

The standard C++ library offers [nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element), which is O(n) on average and very fast in practice. But you would need to either copy both arrays to a temporary before using it, or write a custom iterator which makes it look like the two arrays are one.

Alternatively​, you could code the algorithm yourself, working on both arrays simultaneously.

You will frequently see references to the "median-of-medians" algorithm for finding a pivot in connection with quickselect because median-of-medians can provide a complexity guarantee.  Despite this theoretically interesting  fact, its overhead is huge and practical implementations should avoid it. It is not part of quick
select (or quicksort).

Comment: nice one, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't enough information about your implementation to understand exactly which algorithm you're implementing (would need to see the max_index() and min_index() methods to comment more specifically) this becomes a discussion on why this is taking so long or failing entirely.

Cheat Sheet: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ (See Array Sorting Algorithms)

First, there is Time Complexity.  Time Complexity will determine the amount of computing power needed to run this operation.  If you've implemented a sort that is O(n^2) - worst case scanario for a million records is some factor times 1,000,000,000,000 or multiple trillion operations.  If you've implemented an O(kn) or O(n) time complexity algorithm - you're at some factor times one million for the number of operations.

Second, there is Space Complexity.  That is, how many method calls are added to your stack to complete in memory.  The same basic premise applies here, but instead taking forever, you may simply run out of memory or start using terribly optimized memory caching - which also would significantly increase your time to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to preserve order maybe you could sum all values in both arrays and take the median. Then loop through each array and append to temporary arrays belowMedian or aboveMedian as appropriate by comparing to your median. Then just swap your temporary arrays into your original ones.

Comment: You can't compute the median from the sum, only the average, which does not suffice.

Comment: Ah derp, so a fast sort and get the median from that I suppose, which has probably already been suggested

Answer (score 0):

First off we can see the maximum complexity of your problem. Moving the elements of two collections so that the smaller elements are in one and the larger are in another is a type of sort. Comparison sorting can be at best O(nlogn) complexity. Your answer, however, is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```
 while (1) {                           // while(true) hides that the loop runs worst-case n times
        int mini = max_index(other);   // finding the max or min-element takes O(n)
        int maxi = min_index(data);
        ... //the rest of the loop is constant-time
      }
```

An n-complexity loop that performs n-complexity tasks is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

The naive approach to this problem is to sort both collections, then swap the elements as needed by iterating through the collections (O(nlogn) + O(n) = O(nlogn)), which other answers have suggested.

```
sort(begin(data), end(data));
sort(begin(other), end(other));
for(auto i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
{
    auto& supposed_to_be_smaller = *(begin(data) + i);
    auto& supposed_to_be_bigger = *(begin(other) + i);
    if (supposed_to_be_smaller <= supposed_to_be_bigger)
         break;
    swap(supposed_to_be_smaller, supposed_to_be_bigger);
}
```

Alternatively, since we don't actually care if the elements in each collection is sorted, we only need a partial sort. We only care that the elements in the first collection are smaller than all of the elements of the second. Fortunately, the C++ STL has a function that does this [nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) (Java unfortunately doesn't, but it shouldn't be terribly hard to implement). nth_element ensures that a collection is partially sorted such that the nth element is in the location it would be if sorted and the elements to the left of it are smaller and the elements to the right are bigger. It also runs in O(n) on average. Both collections can be thought of conceptually as a single collection of double the size. Naively you could write concatenate both collections, then nth_element and then split the collection.

```
//combine collections
nth_element(begin(combined), begin(combined) + n, end(combined));
//split collections
```

More elegantly, we can have nth_element write both collections for us by using a custom iterator that operates on both collections simultaneously.

```
custom_iter begin_iter{data, other};
nth_element(begin_iter, begin_iter + n, begin_iter + n * 2);
```

Interestingly this is actually slower than the more naive nth_element.